# how to add fieldnames into json output of C# webservice

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I created some C# webservices that output to JSON

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetCities() {
    SqlConnection myConnection;
    SqlCommand myCommand;
    SqlDataAdapter myAdapter;

    myConnection = new SqlConnection();
    myConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydb"].ConnectionString;

    myCommand = new SqlCommand();
    myCommand.CommandText = "Select DISTINCT AddCity, AddState, AddZip from mytable;";
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

    myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
    myAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);

    // Create a multidimensional jagged array

    string[][] JaggedArray = new string[objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count][];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow rs in objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        JaggedArray[i] = new string[] { rs["AddCity"].ToString(), rs["AddState"].ToString(), rs["AddZip"].ToString()};
        i = i + 1;
    }

    // Return JSON data
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = js.Serialize(JaggedArray);
    return strJSON;        
}
```

The output shows like this:

```
[["UPPER MARLBORO","MD","20772"],["","VA","22301"],["CLINTON","MD","20735"],["GERMANTOWN","MD","20876"],["","VA","22307"],["HUNTINGTOWN","MD","20639"],["GLENARDEN","MD","20774"],["NEWBURG","MD","20664"],  <cont...>
```

I need it to be [["CITY":"UPPER MARLBORO", "ST":"MD", "ZIP":"20772", ....

In short I need fieldnames in the json output.
How do I add it into the script?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON output is exactly as you're describing it in your action. Arrays do not have named fields. You need to use objects if you want named fields. I would use a collection of generic objects, which is more concise and still serializes as an array.

```
var JaggedArray = new List<Object>();
foreach (DataRow rs in objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    JaggedArray.Add(new 
                    { 
                        City = rs["AddCity"].ToString(), 
                        State = rs["AddState"].ToString(), 
                        Zip = rs["AddZip"].ToString()
                    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I see this error: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1526: A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type

Source Error:


Line 85:         // Create a multidimensional jagged array
Line 86: 
Line 87:   var JaggedArray = new List<Object>;
Line 88:   foreach (DataRow rs in objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
Line 89:   {

Comment: NEVERMIND...Realized I was missing {} in List<Object> line and using System.Collections.Generic; in the top.  This is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: I did miss the () on the List constructor. Fixed now.